# How did the first amino acids appear on Earth?

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, molecules

Is there proof or a theory that shows that the first amino acid syntheses on Earth were influenced by a change in heat, gravity, radiation, or something similar?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE. Since there is quite a large(!) gap between the presence of amino acids and the development of life I just want to be sure: You want the answers to your question to concentrate on the first amino acids on earth and not on the first life, right?

Comment: the question is concentrated in the first amino acids on earth what happened any theories or proves?
What happened to atoms to merge into this way

Comment: Are you looking for something like the Miller-Urey experiment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Urey_experiment

Comment: An [earlier question](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/5668/to-model-early-earth-chemical-reactions-which-types-of-reactions-should-be-inclu) maybe a duplicate.

Comment: first life??...

Answer (score -1):

The universe cooled after the Big Bang. There was certainly an epoch when the universe’s overall temperature decreased from 200 °C to −40 °C throughout a *very* large volume. There is your test tube (more like a Florence flask) for abiogenesis and then the panspermia reservoir.

Before you suspect the preceding is clever, how and when (what ambient vacuum temperature) did elements heavier than boron arise?

Comment: Though this answer doesn't directly address the asker's concerns, I have to say you got me. I had never considered the possibility that life in the Universe could have arisen while *the entire thing* was around what we consider ambient temperature, and the idea hit me like a brick for a few seconds. Alas, the Universe cooled down [far too quickly](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=redshift+z+%3D+30&a=FSelect_**LookbackTimeFromRedshift--).

Comment: Redshift z = 140, 10.1 million years old, 111°C radiation temp. A fraction of zero metallicity hypergiant stars might have gone supernova to supply heavier elements, then chemistry. Redshift z = 110, 14.5 million years old, 29°C radiation temp. Complex organics from radiation chemistry with asteroids as substrate. 5-10 million years to evolve even unicellular life buried in asteroids' liquid water inclusions is inadequate. (Somebody post it in physics. It happened in the multiverse!  Once.)